# Update select options based on other selects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter a dataset based on 5 different selects. Each select points to a property in my json file and I want to update the other selects to filter out values which don't exist in the data set after a select has selected an option.

I would also like the select that you filter from to still display other options in there after you select an option. So i dont want the selected select to update its options after it has been used. If that makes sense.

added a jsfiddle for this; 
http://jsfiddle.net/bbup/KN9xx/567/

tried using a function to update the underlying data

```
$scope.updateFilters = function(inVal, inType){
    console.log(inVal + ', ' + inType);       
    $scope.data = _originalData.filter(function(d){
        return d[inType] === inVal;
    });           
};
```

I am new to AngularJS and I hope there is a neat angular solution to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: where are the select lists that you are trying to set up? you only listed the data.

Comment: Look at examples in angular filter docs. Try to get one filter working then expand. When you get stuck post that code along with a demo

Comment: hey this is where i've got to. Have used some sample data. http://jsfiddle.net/bbup/KN9xx/567/